# Undefined symbol for 64 bits architectures

Tags: ios, binaryfiles, tesseract, iphone-64bit

I've just compiled leptonica and tesseract binaries with [this sh file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/85ylsa1smmby6q8/build_dependencies.sh?dl=0). I checked the files with `lipo -info` and this is the result:

```
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/username/Desktop/tess/lib/libtesseract_all.a are: armv7s armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64
Architectures in the fat file: /Users/username/Desktop/tess/lib/liblept.a are: armv7s armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64
```

I think it's supposed to mean that it supports 64bits architectures. But when I imported and used it in my project, this is what I got:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/username/Desktop/project/projectname/tesseract-ios-lib-master/lib/libtesseract_all.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/username/Desktop/project/projectname/tesseract-ios-lib-master/lib/libtesseract_all.a (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/username/Desktop/project/projectname/tesseract-ios-lib-master/lib/liblept.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/username/Desktop/project/projectname/tesseract-ios-lib-master/lib/liblept.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetBoxText(int)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract characterBoxes] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetIterator()", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract getConfidences:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::GetUTF8Text()", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract recognizedText] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetVariable(char const*, char const*)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setVariableValue:forKey:] in Tesseract.o
      -[Tesseract loadVariables] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetRectangle(int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setRect:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, GenericVector<STRING> const*, GenericVector<STRING> const*, bool)", referenced from:
      tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*) in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Version()", referenced from:
      +[Tesseract version] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetImage(Pix const*)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setImage:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Recognize(ETEXT_DESC*)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract recognize] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract initPrivateWithDataPath:language:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::ImageThresholder::GetPixRect()", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setImage:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::ImageThresholder::SetImage(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setImage:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::ImageThresholder::ImageThresholder()", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract setImage:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::PageIterator::BoundingBox(tesseract::PageIteratorLevel, int*, int*, int*, int*) const", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract getConfidences:] in Tesseract.o
  "tesseract::LTRResultIterator::Confidence(tesseract::PageIteratorLevel) const", referenced from:
      -[Tesseract getConfidences:] in Tesseract.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This makes me cannot update my app on the AppStore, since Apple announced that all the apps from February 1st must have 64bits support.

Comment: have you find any soluction?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember how did I solve this. I guess I found something in this article http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial.